# Unable to ssh via cloud shell terminal [google cloud platform]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

It's a couple of days I'm trying to login and use my VM via SSH cloud shell as I always did with no issues.

here the error I got

`Transferring SSH keys to the VM. The key transfer to project metadata is taking an unusually long time. Transferring instead to instance metadata may be faster, but will transfer the keys only to this VM. If you wish to SSH into other VMs from this VM, you will need to transfer the keys accordingly. Click here to transfer the key to instance metadata. Note that this setting is persistent and needs to be disabled in the Instance Details page once enabled. You can drastically improve your key transfer times by migrating to OS Login.`

After digging a bit I found this more detailed error in my connection log:

```
Mar 5 13:46:02 ubuntu-tw google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012
```

I tried to increase my VM disk space, but the result is the same.

At this point I think the easy way is to simply download my scripts there, but how to access the files?

Comment: Do you have some org policies?

Comment: pardon but what is ORG policies? By the way no

Comment: Have you ever been able to login to the VM?  I'd also suggest logging at the serial log of the VM to see that it has booted correctly.

Comment: is there any error on serial console like no space left on device?

Comment: no I don't think so @Mahboob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change or increase the size of your disk first you must create a new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.you can do this with this link [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance)

1. Go to the **[VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances)** creation page

Google Cloud -> Compute Engine ->VM Instances

a. Click the instance name to open the **VM instance details** page.

b. Click **Stop**

c. In the **Boot disk** section, note the boot disk's size and name.

2. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the **[Snapshots](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/snapshotsAdd)** creation page.

Google Cloud -> Compute Engine -> Storage -> Snapshots

a. Enter a snapshot **Name**.

b. Select the boot disk from the **Source disk** drop-down list.

c. Click **Create**.

3. Go to the **VM instances** creation page.

Google Cloud -> Compute Engine ->VM Instances

4. Enter the instance details.
5. Create a new boot disk from the snapshot of the old boot disk.

a. Under **Boot disk**, select **Change**.

b. Select **Snapshots**.

c. Select the snapshot of the old boot disk from the **Snapshot** drop-down list.

d. Select the **Boot disk type**.

e. Enter the new size for the disk.

f. Click **Select** to confirm your disk options.

6. Click **Create**.
7. Mount and format the disk.

Another option is attach the disk to a VM : [Formatting and mounting a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting)

Also I recommended you to do a snapshot or a clone of your disk to avoid the risk of losing the data.

to do this go to [disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks)

Google Cloud -> Compute Engine ->Disks

select your disk and then in the actions toolbar select the option **Create Snapshot** or **Clone disk** to do this.

If you only need to resize your disk you can do it in this part: [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd)

go to your disks page

Google Cloud -> Compute Engine ->Disks

1. Click on your **disk name**
2. Click on the **edit** button
3. in **Properties** you can change the size of your disk
4. Click on **Save** button

Then you need to restart your VM and your changes there will be applied

**Edit 03082021**

found this, to access via serial console: [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#console)

**Edit 03092021**

for add or remove the SSH keys you need to follow this next steps:
[Adding or removing project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide)

To add or remove project-wide public SSH keys from the Cloud Console :

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the metadata page for your project.
   [Go to the Metadata page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata/sshKeys)
2. Under **SSH Keys**, click **Edit**.
3. Modify the project-wide public SSH keys:

To add a public SSH key, click **Add item**. A text box opens.

Copy and paste the contents of your [public SSH key file](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#locatesshkeys) into the text box.

Repeat this process for each public SSH key that you want to add.

To remove a public SSH key, click the removal button next to it:
[image]

Repeat this process for each public SSH key that you want to remove.

4. When you have finished editing the SSH keys, click **Save**.

and here you create a new SSH key [Creating a new SSH key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys)

Open a terminal on your workstation

run this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
```

**Replace the following:**

`[KEY_FILENAME]` : the name that you want to use for your SSH key files. For example, a filename of `my-ssh-key`generates a private key file named `my-ssh-key`and a public key file named `my-ssh`

`[USERNAME]`: the name of the user connecting to the VM. For example, `youremail@gmail.com`

here is an example:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my-new-ssh-key -C myficticialmail@gmail.com
```

The next is choose a passphrase that you remember and confirm the passphrase

2. Restrict access to your private key so that only you can read it and nobody can write to it

   `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME]`

where `[KEY_FILENAME]` is the name that you used for your SSH key files.

Repeat this process for every user who needs a new key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it didn't work out, it simply replicare the issue on the new VM. At this point I think the easy way is to download all my files and simply restart a new VM. But I didn't figure out how to download my files?

Comment: I update my answer and added how to connect via serial console

Comment: you are very kind now checking my ssh keys I just noticed that they are expired, can you kindly point me how to renovate them?

Comment: I update the answer with the instructions to how add and remove your SSH keys

Comment: I edited my answer and put the steps to add and remove your ssh keys, just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers